# Using two DLL files from PowerShell when one DLL file references the other one

Tags: .net, dll, powershell, .net-4.0, gac

I got two DLL files in the GAC.

DLL file A references DLL file B.

From a PowerShell script I'm using the following method to load the DLL files:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(full name of dll B)
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load(full name of dll A)
```

Despite this when DLL file A needs to use some class from B I get the following error.

> Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\B.dll'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both dlls are in the same directory you could try:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadfrom(full name of dll A)
```

Comment: This solved it. But it was an accident: we had always run scripts as Administrator before but my college ran it as a normal user once then it worked. By that time Load was replaced with LoadFrom. 
Still confused why does it matter what privileges a user has in this case...

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
Add-Type -Path path\to\A.dll
```